# Problems with Pagination on Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the next problem

I have a table called employments on mysql, and this table have the column idbusiness that's reference to table business.

Well, My employments are like this

> id  | idbusiness | name | address

This is the line on my function for pagination:

```
$employments = employments::paginate(10)->onEachSide(5);
```

And my code in the showemploymets.blade.php

```
{{$empleados->appends(request()->except('showemployments'))->links()}}
```

The problem is when I select the IDBusiness = 1 its ok, show me all the employments from IDBusiness = 1, but when I select the IDBusiness = 2 o 3 o 4

They show me the selected employments up to page XX and not in the first page...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show the controller method with `employments::paginate(10)->onEachSide(5);`

Also, if you can, post the JSON output of IDBusiness on and the other IDBusiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

**Controller File**

```
public function cities()
{
    $cities = App\City::paginate(2);
    return view('welcome', compact('cities'));
}
```

**Blade File**

```
{{ $cities->onEachSide(3)->links() }}
```

---

Description :

`onEachSide(1)` show the number of pages before and after **ACTIVE** page.

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfftK.png)

For example consider we are at page 30 we have pagination of 5 and total number of records 355 than:

```
{{ $cities->onEachSide(1)->links() }}
```

1 2 .. **29** 30 **31** .. 66 67

---

```
{{ $users->onEachSide(2)->links() }}
```

1 2 .. **28 29** 30 **31 32**  .. 66 67

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this took me way too long to figure out for Laravel 5.7.
This was my error and I hope this helps you out as well.

I'm using nginx as a webserver so this probably only applies to that webserver.
It's very important to have this line with the query_string at the end:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string
```

I'll post the whole config if you want but this should help you.