# Laravel 5.7 (latest) Pagination Bug (Stays on 1'st page Only no matter what pagination link you click)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Link to the same question (WASN't ANSWERED): [Problems with Pagination on Laravel 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697821/problems-with-pagination-on-laravel-5-7)

It wouldn't let me comment or bump, I am having the same issue as this user with 5.7 alone. I am surprised after how long it been out now, nobody has answered it already.

Screen shot below of `dd()` of my `$admins = Admin::latest()->paginate(1);`

[image: Screenshot]

My controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $admins = Admin::latest()->paginate(1);
        return view('admin.settings.admins.index', compact('admins'));
    }
```

My blade file:

```
<!--begin::Portlet-->
            <div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile m-portlet--body-progress-">
                <div class="m-portlet__head">
                    <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
                        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
                            <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">
                                Admins
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="m-portlet__body">
                    <div class="m-portlet__body-progress">Loading</div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($admins as $admin)
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{ $admin->id }}</th>
                                <td><a href="{{ url('/'.config('app.admin_path').'/settings/admins/'.$admin->id.'/') }}">{{ $admin->last_name }}, {{ $admin->first_name }}</a></td>
                                <td><a href="{{ url('/'.config('app.admin_path').'/settings/admins/'.$admin->id.'/') }}">{{ $admin->email }}</a></td>
                                <td>@if($admin->status == 1)
                                        Active
                                @elseif($admin->status == 2)
                                        InActive
                                @else
                                        <font style="color:red;">Terminated</font>
                                @endif
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div>
                        {{ $admins->appends(Request::all())->links() }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end::Portlet-->
```

Any help is greatly appreicated as this has been a struggle and i still have yet to solve it.

My Database Rows:

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5W8y.png)

Comment: Clearly from the image i posted, you can see that something is really wrong because in my URL bar it says ?page=3 yet the JSON output says Page is 1.

Comment: How many records do you have in your DB and how many you are showing on one page?

Comment: 1 per page and 4 as the JSON displays

Comment: Please post you controller and model and verify your database records once again for me.

Comment: I posted controller and i posted db rows proof.

Comment: As well as the blade file.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with it. can you try removing latest function.

Comment: @RafayHassan I already tried that and it did not work either.

Comment: @JarrodEstepp: please see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination)

Comment: How is the pagination page supposed to help me? I have already ran through it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this took me way too long to figure out.
This was my error and I hope this helps you out as well.

I'm using nginx as a webserver so this probably only applies to that webserver.
It's very important to have this line with the query_string at the end:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string
```

I'll post the whole config if you want but this should help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

**Controller File**

```
public function cities()
{
    $cities = App\City::paginate(2);
    return view('welcome', compact('cities'));
}
```

**Blade File**

```
{{ $cities->onEachSide(3)->links() }}
```

---

Description :

`onEachSide(1)` show the number of pages before and after **ACTIVE** page.

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfftK.png)

For example consider we are at page 30 we have pagination of 5 and total number of records 355 than:

```
{{ $cities->onEachSide(1)->links() }}
```

1 2 .. **29** 30 **31** .. 66 67

---

```
{{ $users->onEachSide(2)->links() }}
```

1 2 .. **28 29** 30 **31 32**  .. 66 67

Comment: I will look into this! :D

Comment: This did not fix my issue, sorry.

Comment: @JarrodEstepp I guess you are trying on the first page of pagination. On the first page, you can't see because there is not before page. You see the onEachSide(num) after **min - 4 to 6** pages. still, you want to see for demo purpose then use paginate of 1 and onEachSide use 0 so you see the screen but it is not good think for projects.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

`{{ $admins->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}`

If you are getting data via GET request or query string parameter, you need to include those query string on each page request without page parameter.

Since you have appended all from request, 'page=1' is included on the query string as well, thus stays in page 1 forever.